# Unable to Set local group policy using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, group-policy

I try to set local group policy using PowerShell. My goal is to enable

> Disable changing home page settings

Below is the PowerShell script:

```
# Set the values as needed
$dchps_control_panel = "HKCU:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Control Panel"
$dchps_main = "HKCU:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main"
$homepage = "HomePage"
$enabled = 1
$startpage = "Start Page"
$startpage_value = "www.google.com"

# Test if the Registry Key exists already
if(-not (Test-Path $dchps_control_panel) -or -not (Test-Path $dchps_main) )
{
    # Create Control Panel Key to enable and Main Key
    New-Item -Path $dchps_control_panel -Force
    New-Item -Path $dchps_main -Force
}

# Enable Disable changing home page settings
Set-ItemProperty -Path $dchps_control_panel -Name $homepage -Value $enabled -Type DWord
#
# Set Start Page
Set-ItemProperty -Path $dchps_main -Name $startpage  -Value $startpage_value -Type String
```

The registry keys both get created. However, when I check the "gpedit.msc" the setting still remains to disable and nothing was configured.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use the GP cmdlets?

Comment: As far as I can remember that's by design.  gpedit.msc doesn't display registry-based policy.  You should probably be asking on Server Fault, however, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: The setting shows up in a different registry location on my Win10 machine. Testing a few scenarios to see if it's consistent between machines.